# What is meaning & cause of getting [0 x1 double] in output of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, types, double, terminology

Lets say,we are trying to execute a code in MATLAB,but in output we are getting one of results as 0 x1 double, i know that its referring to double data type, but here in MATLAB ,what is its meaning &  what is its cause/reason(How it is produced)

Forexample try to run the following MATLAB code:

```
clc
clear all
close all
R=1*10^3
C=1*10^-6
num=[-1]
den=[R*C 0]
sys=tf(num,den)
[z,p,k]=zpkdata(sys)
```

**Here we get in output z=[0 x 1] double**

what is its reason?why/how we get result of this type double?Why we didn't get normal numeric result ?

Comment: You are getting an array of size 0x1. That is, it is an array with 0 values in it, it’s empty. I don’t know the functions you are using, so I can’t tell you the reason you don’t get what you expect. I suggest reading the documentation for them, that usually clarifies things.

Comment: "That is, it is an array with 0 values in it," how many zeros?

Comment: With no values in it. The size is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your defined system has none zeros and 1 pole. Therefore, z is a empty matrix with dimension 0x1